# Angular: how to destroy a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, destroy

In my word-cloud application I have 2 directives, a word cloud directive and table directive that when a word in the word cloud is selected, it notify to the table so the table will also select the correspond word. The word-cloud and the table communicate by promise which resides in the service, and I want to destroy the promise:

**service code:**

```
this.selectedDefferd = $q.defer(); 

this.selectedPromise = this.selectedDefferd.promise;

   notifySelect(id)
   {
        this.selectedDefferd.notify({newData: this.data[id]});
    }

 setSelect(callBack) {
    this.selectedPromise.then(null, null, callBack);
}
```

**word cloud directive code :**

```
d3.select(this).on("click", function (d) {
...
ctrl.wordService.notifySelect(d.id);
}
```

**table directive**

```
var selectCallback = $(".selected");

wordService.setSelect(selectCallback);
```

Thanks  in advance,

Harel

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "destroy"? Why do you want that, and what good is it?

Comment: $element.on("$destroy", function () {
            console.log("wordCloud controller destroyed");
        })
In order to avoid memory leak

Comment: You can just `this.selectedDefferd = null`, but I don't think it would lead to a memory leak otherwise either.

Comment: `notify` is an awful API, I recommend against it. I would personally just use an event emitter for this. Notification in promises isn't sound and doesn't work very well.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum what do u mean "event emitter"?

Answer (score 0):

With reject() you can reject a promise

```
this.selectedDefferd.reject('Rejected!');
```

The 2nd parameter of the promise is for the rejection.

```
promise.then(function(greeting) {
  alert('Success: ' + greeting);
}, function(reason) {
  alert('Failed: ' + reason);
}, function(update) {
  alert('Got notification: ' + update);
});
```